# How to use SQL Server agent to run a Powershell command to generate a CSV file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-server-agent

I have a PowerShell command like this:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | FT Name 
      > C:\Users\hou\Downloads\DisabledAccount.csv
```

This command can grab all disabled account names from AD and put it into a `.CSV` file.

I want to set up a job in SQL Server agent so it will run the command whenever I need it.

But the Agent keep gives me error when I was trying to run the job.

Can anyone let me know the right command for this while running in SQL Server agent?

Comment: `But the Agent keep gives me error when I was trying to run the job.` Share error message

Comment: The command should be `Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Export-CSV -notypeinformation C:\Users\hou\Downloads\DisabledAccount.csv`. You didnt have a csv file... just a text file. Sure the error was about the input file.

Comment: Do I need to add something like Invoke xxxx before the command. Cuz this will comes out when I try to run it: The term 'Search-ADAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function scriot file or operable program @Matt

Comment: That was the error you were getting? Well this means that you do not have the activedirectory module available where you are running this code.

Comment: I do have AD Module enabled and I can run my code under powershell and generate a csv file without any problem, it just dont let me do that using SQL Server Job Agent. dont understand.

Comment: Your powershell session might load it but it does not mean sql will. Possibly just need to add `import-module activedirectory`. Also use the @ symbol to ping users you are chatting to. I didnt know you responded until I checked just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have other issues but the glaring first one you have is you do *not* have a CSV file. If you opened the file you would see that it is not following any CSV standard but that of a formatted table.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | 
    Export-CSV -notypeinformation C:\Users\hou\Downloads\DisabledAccount.csv
```

`Format-Table` is just for showing information on the screen. Not for use of generating output. If you want to make a CSV then that is what `Export-CSV` is there to do. If you only wanted the name column then you could add a `Select-Object` in the pipe.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | 
    Select-Object Name |
    Export-CSV -notypeinformation C:\Users\hou\Downloads\DisabledAccount.csv
```

Comment: Do I need to add something like Invoke xxxx before the command. Cuz this will comes out when I try to run it: The term 'Search-ADAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function scriot file or operable program